# how to echo variable outside of class, passing from function within class

Tags: php, function, class, scope

I have a php code.
my code is like this 
`class Connection {`
`function connect(){`
`$link = 'Connected';` 
`}` 
`}`

`$con = new Connection();`
    `$con -> connect();`
`echo $con->link;//connected`

here i want to echo the variable but it is not getting
Help me

Answer (score 2):

You will have to `return` a value, like this:

```
function connect() {
    return 'Connected';
}
```

Comment: If you want this information to be dynamic your `class` should have "getter's and setter's". IE: `$con.setState();` `$con.getState();` the former having a return statement built in to it. I don't know what the overall purpose is but with OOP try to code with a purpose and be predictable.

Comment: Thank you it is working only for returning one value but i have to echo another variables also so how it is working